# What is the difference between the different types of snowboards? (all-mountain/freestyle/freeride/etc)

Tags: snowboarding

I'm looking into buying my first snowboard, and there's all kinds of types:

- All mountain
- Freestyle
- Freeride
- Splitboards
- Powder

What's the difference between these types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The different types of snowboards are:

**All-mountain**: Versatile snowboards that can be used on all parts of the mountain, including machine-groomed runs, backcountry, and park and pipe.

**Freestyle**: Boards that are light, short, and flexible, and ideal for terrain parks and doing tricks (riding rails, jibbing, etc)

**Freeride**: Boards that are ideal for backcountry riding and going fast on groomed runs.

**Splitboards**: Boards that can split in half for backcountry climbing.

**Powder**: Boards that will spend most of their time in deep powder. They have wide waists, wide noses, and are generally rocker shaped to prevent the edges from catching.

Sourced from [REI](http://www.rei.com/expertadvice/articles/snowboard.html).

Comment: And what about [Gullwing shape](http://whitelines.mpora.com/product/nitro-team-gullwing-snowboard.html)? Which category does it belongs to?

Comment: @Tomas A Gullwing is sort of a Rocker type, so turns easier. It depends on the flex of the board in which category it sticks, but you see them a lot on freestyle /park boards.